# Generate xs:date instead of xs:dateTime for WebParam

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I have a jax-ws web-service with web-method:

```
@WebMethod
void SetCurrentDate(Date date)
```

In generated wsdl parameter date has type xs:dateTime, but i need xs:date.
I tried XmlGregorianCalendar, but it maps to xs:anySimpleType, also i tried @XmlSchemaType, but it's not allowed for parameters.
How can I generate wsdl with xsd:date instead of xsd:dateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like only way to do it is by using annotation @RequestWrapper (for jax-ws-impl and apache cxf):

```
@WebMethod
@RequestWrapper(className = "....SetCurrentDateRequest")
void SetCurrentDate(Date date)
```

And request wrapper:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "setCurrentDateRequest", propOrder = {
    "date"
})
public class SetCurrentDateRequest {

    @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
    protected Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

[CXF/JAXB Code-first service: modify XMLSchemaType of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057203/cxf-jaxb-code-first-service-modify-xmlschematype-of-inputs)

Answer (score 0):

[**@XmlSchemaType**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchemaType.html) is enough to do it.
Both

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected Date publishDate;
```

and

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar publishDate;
```

are generated to `type="xs:date"` (with `schemagen` tool)

See examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchemaType.html)

**Example 1:** Customize mapping of XMLGregorianCalendar on the field.

```
 //Example: Code fragment
 public class USPrice {
     @XmlElement
     @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
     public XMLGregorianCalendar date;
 }

 <!-- Example: Local XML Schema element -->
 <xs:complexType name="USPrice"/>
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
   </sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
```

**Example 2:** Customize mapping of XMLGregorianCalendar at package level

```
 package foo;
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(
      name="date", type=javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar.class)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I read about this, but I need generate xsd:date for method argument, not for class field. Do you know way to do it?